# OpenGL shader is not getting a value from glVertexAttribPointer()

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

Although I call `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glVertexAttribPointer`, my vertex shader cannot seem to access the value (I say value because i am not sure what it is called, Attribute?).

I am confused as I have other values that the vertex shader can access by doing exactly the same thing.

In the following code the Vertex position in attribute position 0 and the Vertex normal in attribute position 1 can be accessed fine by the shader however when I use the Vertex color value in attribute position 2 as the color for my mesh it is black even if set otherwise.

```cpp
//Vertex Position
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, vertexPosition));

//Vertex Normal
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, vertexNormal));

//Vertex Colour
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, vertexColor));
```

Here is the Vertex struct

```cpp
struct Vertex {

    glm::vec3 vertexPosition;
    glm::vec3 vertexNormal;
    glm::vec3 vertexColor;

    glm::vec2 textureCoords;

    glm::vec3 vertexTangent;
    glm::vec3 vertexBitangent;

    Vertex() {}

    Vertex(glm::vec3 vertexPosition, glm::vec3 vertexNormal = glm::vec3(0), glm::vec3 vertexColor = glm::vec3(0), glm::vec2 textureCoords = glm::vec2(0)) {
        this->vertexPosition = vertexPosition;
        this->vertexNormal = vertexNormal;
        this->textureCoords = textureCoords;
    }

};
```

Here is the Shader code. If I uncomment the commented line the mesh renders red as expected

```
#version 330 core

uniform mat4 uModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 uViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;
uniform vec3 uLightPosition;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 aVertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aVertexNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 aVertexColor;

out vec3 viewDirection;
out vec3 lightPosition;
out vec3 fragmentPosition;
out vec3 materialColor;
flat out vec3 fragmentNormal;

void main(){

    materialColor = aVertexColor;
    //materialColor = vec3(0.5, 0, 0);

    mat4 modelViewMatrix = uViewMatrix * uModelMatrix;

    vec3 viewSpacePosition = (modelViewMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1)).xyz;
    viewDirection = normalize(viewSpacePosition);

    vec3 viewSpaceNormal = normalize(modelViewMatrix * vec4(aVertexNormal, 0)).xyz;
    fragmentNormal = viewSpaceNormal;
    fragmentNormal = aVertexNormal;

    lightPosition = uLightPosition;

    fragmentPosition = vec3(uModelMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0));

    gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1);
}
```

Even if vertexColor defaults to `glm::vec3(1)` instead of `glm::vec3(0)` it is still black. I have checked the values for vertexColor before drawing with the shader and the color is *not* black.

Comment: Let me know if you require any more information.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not setting your vertexColor value in the Vertex constructor.

```
Vertex(glm::vec3 vertexPosition, glm::vec3 vertexNormal = glm::vec3(0), glm::vec3 vertexColor = glm::vec3(0), glm::vec2 textureCoords = glm::vec2(0)) {
        this->vertexPosition = vertexPosition;
        this->vertexNormal = vertexNormal;
        this->vertexColor = vertexColor;
    }
```

Comment: Not neccesarily, In most cases it is set after construction. However even if this value is initialized in the constructor it doesn't make any change. See the note at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Also I do exactly the same with the vertexNormal in the constructor as I do with the color and then set it at a later date and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Must have missed that, share the initial part of your shader code too?

Comment: Sorry, yeah should definetly have added the shader code.

Comment: materialColor = aVertexColor;
materialColor = vec3(0.5, 0, 0);

This meant to be overriding it?

lol, commented out now ;)

Comment: Yes the second one is commented out. It was just used to test whether aVertexColor was actually the problem or whether materialColor was. If materialColor is set to vec3(0.5, 0, 0) e.g. red then the mesh draws red as expected